# moment.js cannot parse date correctly

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Thanks for reading, I got a date that get's returned from sharepoint as '`10/2/2000 12:00:00 AM`' This didn't work with moment.js and locales so I reparsed it to a ISOString, now the data '`2000-10-01T22:00:00.000Z`' as specified as in: https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/1407 . However it will still fallback to the standard javascript Date function and I have no idea why.

Below is my code implementation:

Code for parsing in momentJs

```
function dayAndFullMonth(dateTime, timezone) {
    return moment.tz(dateTime, timezone).format('DD MMM');
}
```

The function responsible for rewriting the date

```
function rewriteDates()
{
    var endPartArray = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i< vm.birthdays.length; i++)
    {
        var birthday = sharepointservice.getProperty(vm.birthdays[i].Cells, 'Birthday');
        console.log(birthday);
        var cleanBirthday = new Date(birthday.split(' ')[0]).toISOString();
        console.log(cleanBirthday);

        var dutchDates = dateservice.dayAndFullMonth(cleanBirthday, "Europe/Amsterdam");
        console.log(dutchDates);
    }
}
```

my console:

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you're calling moment.tz, but it should just be moment('10/2/2000 12:00:00 AM').  That will parse correctly and allow you to call format.

**After Edit**

You need to include moment-timezone, not just moment.  I've tested your code here: https://npm.runkit.com/moment-timezone and it works fine.

Comment: sorry for not being clear enough, I use the moment.tz, because I have to translate the date from  an English to a Dutch format and it seems that it can parse the date but cannot translate it.

Comment: I've updated my answer - it appears you might not be including moment-timezone.

Comment: If this solved your issue, would you please mark it as correct?  Thanks!

Comment: Sorry I wasn't online for some time. Your comment made a pointer in the right direction, I included my code though. in the end I solved it by setting moment.locale('nl') within the dayAndFullMonth function.

function 
dayAndFullMonth(dateTime, timezone) {
    moment.locale('nl')
    return moment.tz(dateTime, timezone).format('DD MMM');
}